# ¿Cómo Combinar dos arrays en uno php?

Tags: php

Estoy un poco empezando con `php` esto y me preguntaba si es posible combinar dos `arrays`, mas o menos mi idea es esta:

```
 $fruits = array("id"=>"1", "name"=>"banana");
   $vegetables = array("id"=>"1", "name"=>"cabbage");
   foreach($fruits as $fruit)
   {               
      $results = array("id"=>$fruit->id, "description"=>$fruit->name);
   }
  // $results = array("id"=>" ", "description"=>" ");
   return $results;
```

Quiero saber si puedo retornar, esos dos `array` dentro de uno solo, con esas dos keys "`id`" y "`description`", hay algún método para hacerlo? he intentado con `array_fill_keys` pero no funciono. gracias.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Crea un arreglo y agrega los valores de los otros arreglos al final del primer arreglo:

```
$results = array();
$results[] = $fruits;
$results[] = $vegetables;
return $results;
```

Por tu comentario, lo que necesitas no es solo unir los arreglos en un arreglo multidimensional, sino también agregar una función de mapeo para todos los elementos de este nuevo arreglo multidimensional. Puedes utilizar [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) para mapear los elementos del nuevo array multidimensional en uno nuevo con los datos que requieres.

```
$results = array();
$results[] = $fruits;
$results[] = $vegetables;
$mapeo = function($elemento) {
    return array(
        'id' => $elemento['id'],
        'description' => $elemento['name']
        );
}
return array_map($mapeo, $results);
```

La función `array_map` hará lo siguiente:

1. Recorrer los elementos de `$results` provisto en el segundo argumento.
2. Para cada elemento, aplicará la función `$mapeo` provista en el primer argumento.
3. Devolver como resultado un arreglo nuevo que posea el resultado de aplicar `$mapeo` a cada elemento de `$results`.

Considerando que esto es lo que buscas, el código puede reducirse a:

```
$mapeo = function($elemento) {
    return array(
        'id' => $elemento['id'],
        'description' => $elemento['name']
        );
}
return array_map($mapeo, array($fruits, $vegetables));
```

---

Nota: estoy usando lambdas, habilitadas en PHP desde 5.3.0

Comment: Gracias, eso me funciona, ahora bien, ¿no hay manera de asignarle el valor a cada key, en caso de que los campos no coincidan? si una tabla tiene 5 campos y la otra 3, como se que los nombres van a ir en la key "description"?

Comment: Ok, lo que tú buscas es hacer una especie de mapeo desde tus datos hacia un nuevo arreglo. Eso no es tan sencillo. Lo que debes hacer luego que has *unido* tus arreglos en un arreglo multidimensional, es navegar a través del arreglo multidimensional y mapearlo hacia el nuevo esquema que gustas o deseas. Voy a agregar un ejemplo sobre lo que ya tengo. Ahora, déjame adelantarte de que necesitas establecer cuál es la nueva manera de que deberán lucir los datos.

Comment: Exacto, un arreglo multidimensional, lo que busco es recorrer mi arreglo, para luego pasarle los valores que yo quiera al otro, claro, especificando las keys para luego poder acceder a ellas. mmm en Java hacia una tabla temporal pero veo que en php no existe tal cosa

Comment: En este caso, `$results` es el arreglo multidimensional. He editado la respuesta para satisfacer tu nueva duda. Recomiendo que actualices la pregunta para que refleje que lo que buscas es unir 2 o más arreglos en un arreglo multidimensional y mapearlos hacia un nuevo tipo de arreglo (esto claro, basado en tus comentarios).

Comment: pff es lo que buscaba, voy a partir de allí para ver si puedo unir todos los arreglos que necesito, muchas gracias Luiggi

Comment: De nada Daniel. Si esta respuesta contesta a tu pregunta, por favor [acéptala](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/427/227).

Answer (score 4):

Mírate la función [array_mege() del propio PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php)

EL ejemplo que ponen:

```
<?php
$array1    = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2    = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);

$resultado = array_merge($array1, $array2);

print_r($resultado);
?>
```

El resultado del ejemplo sería:

```
Array
(
    [color] => green
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => a
    [3] => b
    [shape] => trapezoid
    [4] => 4
)
```

Comment: Si, lo acabo de intentar con ese, pero cuando retorna el array me pierde el valor de '$vegetables->name', leí algo sobre arrays multidimensionales, intentare a ver, gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: @danielvkp no habia visto esta respuesta, por lo que agregue un similar. saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Usando el método [**array_merge()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
<?php
$fruits =  array("id"=>"1", "name"=>"banana");
$vegetables= array("id"=>"1", "name"=>"cabbage");
$result = array_merge($fruits , $vegetables);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Ejemplo:

Ejemplo **array_merge() http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php**

```
<?php
$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

El ejemplo tendría una salida:

```
Array
(
    [color] => green
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => a
    [3] => b
    [shape] => trapezoid
    [4] => 4
)
```